Is there a way to configure nginx to proxy-pass minio traffic and handle authentication from itself?
The scenario:
It is a completely secured network with multiple app clients accessing via nginx to a minio cluster. However the buckets are set as private and PBAC. Each app knows where their files are i.e: the bucket/path/name of object
There is an nginx which reverse-proxy the traffic front of minio cluster. I want to set access/secret keys inside the configuration of the nginx, so that the applications only request the URLs and nginx does the authentication. The reason to do that is that the nginx is managed by the storage team and apps are managed by developers. We want to secure minio internally so that no other apps or rogue nodes can access to the minio while not revealing any passwords to the developers.
If behind the nginx there was a simple authentication mechanism in the proxy_pass directive we could set:
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic <base64 converted uname:password>";
proxy_pass_header Authorization;

How can I achieve the same with minio authentication?Appreciate any help please

Just use proxy_set_header with a name/vaule as described in (e.g.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773176/minio-create-and-list-a-bucket-with-curl

This approach is not recommended and correct. Apps usually connect to MinIO API using SDKs. These API endpoints (and each Bucket behind them) should be protected using a pair of access_key and secret_key. So in this approach, you don't need authentication in other layers and MinIO can cope with it.
In addition, you shouldn't reveal any password that belongs to the production environment at all. You should use a CI/CD pipeline and inject the password into the pipeline. For tests, dev, or staging environments you should use an identical MinIO and give its access_key and secret_key to developers since this is not a production server.
You can use authentication in nginx just for MinIO web console, but this is not necessary and MinIO has a login page itself.
If you want to configure the reverse proxy in your config file add:
upstream minio {
        server myserver:9000;
}

upstream console {
        server myserver:9001;
}

And
server {
    server_name  api.myminio.com;
    ...
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://minio;
    }
}

server {
    server_name  console.myminio.com;
    ...
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://console;
    }
 
}


Thanks but no thanks, should or should not wasn't the point here in the first place.Also very well defined and documented it is at Minio docs with examples.
